# Call javascript method with order

Tags: javascript, function

I have 3 methods in JavaScript and I want to call one after the other, that is to say in order.

```
recuperer_from_proposer_liste_idchamp();
nombre_etape();
```

Comment: so what is the question?

Comment: They are running in order, as long as you not have some asynchronously magic in there. And again: The question is?...

Comment: how I can do, because they are so called async.

Comment: you have 3 method, but the code show 2. and they **are** in order

Comment: I've you have some asynchronous magic in there you have to handle with callback functions.

Comment: function recuperer_from_proposer_liste_idchamp()  //La methode a appeler lors de la click sur le boutton
{
 db =window.openDatabase("bYzance", "1.0", "PhoneGap Demo", 921600);
   
    db.transaction(recuper_liste_id_from_proposer, erreur_rec_proposer);
 
}

Answer (score 1):

Unless there are any asynchronous calls (such as AJAX requests) those methods will run in the order you type them.

The JavaScript interpreter executes commands line-by-line.

If you have asynchronous calls, then those will need to be handled with callback functions. If you don't understand how callbacks work, there are lots of [guides online](http://recurial.com/programming/understanding-callback-functions-in-javascript/).

Comment: @AzeazeAzeaze That has no relevance to your question or my answer.

Comment: @Jivings: I think most JS SQLite APIs are asynchronous

Comment: @ThiefMaster I see, that would make more sense perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

If you do are doing something asyncronous you have to find out when the methods have finished their work. So call method 1:

```
method1 ();
```

method1 then needs to inform us about the end of it's action and for that it has to call a method called method1_finished which then calls method2:

```
method1_finished () {
    method2 ();
}
```

The same goes for method 3:

```
method2_finished () {
    method3 ();
}
```

Depending on where the code comes from you are often able to define an anonymous function directly where a callback is required:

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
{
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
  {
        // call succeeded, now go on to the next step
  }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","someurl.php",true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

Answer (score 0):

You may have to change your logic to something like this

```
function getRowsFromDatabase(callback) {
    // do your fancy database connection
    // and data retrieval here

    // when you're ready, call the registered callback

    if(typeof(callback) == "function") {
        callback(rowsRetrieved);
    }
}


function displayRowsOnScreen() {
    getRowsFromDatabase(function(rows){
        // do the dom magic here
    })
}
```